# Magento2 Extending Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct Class

Tags: magento2, blocks, related-products, up-sells, cross-sells

I wanted to add some extra custom methods to the block classes:

- Related
- Upsell
- Cross-sell

Each of these extends the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`

But using `di.xml` preference I was not able to overwrite the abstract class, maybe because Magento does not allow that.

I wanted to know if there is a way to add the common functionality to each of these blocks, without individually overwrite each of them and repeating the same code.

Comment: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct is not an abstract class,, it's just simple class .

Comment: @KeyurShah, Yes I know. I was still not able to overwrite/extend this class using di.xml `<preference/>`. I was thinking maybe like in Magento1 we could not `<rewrite/>` the class having Abstract in their class name does same apply for Magento2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can't override classes having "Abstract" keyword in Magento.
Alternatively, you can override the class \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View as it is the child class of \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct, it should possesses all the property's and functions of it's base class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overwrite abstract classes. Individual classes directly extend their respective parent classes using the `extends` keyword.

Seeing as this is PHP native code and is therefore not handled by Magento's Object Manager there is no way to hook into this.

Regards,
Vincent