# magento2 extends block from class have abstract

Tags: magento2.3

I have lass

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\RateProducts\Block\Frontend;

class FeaturedProduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_productloader;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productloader,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_productloader = $productloader;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $productCollection = $this->_productloader->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productCollection->setPageSize(5)->addFieldToFilter('homepage_featured',1)->setCurPage(1)->load();
    return $productCollection;
}
```

}

now i want extends class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Product;


class AbstractProduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
...
}
```

How can i extends it. I have try write but not working

Comment: check this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123590/magento2-extending-magento-catalog-block-product-abstractproduct-class , https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159215/override-magento-catalog-block-product-abstractproduct-getaddtocarturl-functio/223935

Comment: What do you mean? 
Like that `class FeaturedProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`

Comment: @ThaoPham yes it mean

Comment: What do you want do to exactly ? What is the goal of now i want extends class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct

Comment: @Claims it mean i want class FeaturedProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct to i use function in class AbstractProduct in phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> it mean i want class FeaturedProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct to i use function in class AbstractProduct in phtml file

I think what you are looking for is a preference.

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct" type="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" />
```

Doing this, AbstractProduct execution will replace Template.

Then you can just extends the AbstractProduct with your FeatureProduct as you are trying to do.

But you should only use preference with custom files I think, so the best would be to get your own AbstractProduct in the first place I think ? Not sure though

Comment: your mean etc/frontend/di.xml will add this line and my file php will extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct

Comment: Yes : take a look here to the method number 2 : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html 
You might need to compile again after adding the preference.